# Android Webview Cookies Getting are Cleared after App

Tags: android, asp.net, angular, webview

I have an android app which is using webview to display angular 8 website.

I'm able to use the app perfectly fine on first login. Every subsequent request that is being sent to the server has cookies added to in request headers.

But Once I close the app, cookies are no longer there.
The app is asking to log in again.

I have tried adding following lines:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);
        }
    }
```

```
     @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
     super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
     
     if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
         mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
     }
```

Basically, I want to persist the cookies and not have them cleared after subsequent restarts.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `CookieManager.getInstance().flush()` in your `onPageFinished`

**flush()**: Ensures all cookies currently accessible through the getCookie API are written to persistent storage. This call will block the caller until it is done and may perform I/O.